# What is the command and syntax for breaking/stopping a program in QBASIC?

Tags: qbasic

I am currently writing a QBASIC program that runs an indefinite loop (while loop). However, if a certain condition is met, I want to exit the program. What command do I use, and also what is the syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`END`exits program, and clears all variables, which frees up memory.
`STOP`exits program, but retains the value of all variables, which makes it possible (in certain versions of QB) to continue execution at another point, by choosing `Set next statement` from the `Debug`menu, and then `Start`from the `Run`menu. `END` has the same effect as `STOP` + choosing `Restart` from the `Run`menu once the program has terminated.

If you have a loop, and want to exit the program from inside it, you may use either

`DO
IF condition THEN EXIT DO
LOOP
END`

or

`DO
IF condition THEN END
LOOP`

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [`END`](http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/END) or [`SYSTEM`](http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/SYSTEM) statement. For example:

```
PRINT "Hello World!"
END
PRINT "This won't be printed."
```

If you're using regular old QBASIC/QuickBASIC, then you can ignore all of the QB64 details on the linked pages and just use either `SYSTEM` or `END`. Both will do the same thing for the most part.<sup>1</sup>

If you're using FreeBASIC, it's recommended to use `END` instead of `SYSTEM` since some things won't get cleaned up properly when you use `SYSTEM`. See [`SYSTEM`](http://www.freebasic.net/wiki/KeyPgSystem) for more information pertaining to FreeBASIC if that's what you're using.

---

<sup>1</sup> The `END` statement when running the program using `QB.EXE /RUN PROGRAM.BAS` will print "Press any key to continue" before exiting to the QB/QBASIC environment. The `SYSTEM` statement when run the same way will simply return you to the DOS shell without any need for a key press. Also, typing `SYSTEM` in the "Immediate Window" of the QB/QBASIC environment will exit the environment and return to the DOS shell. Otherwise the two statements behave exactly the same in QB/QBASIC, whether for standalone (compiled) programs or `.BAS` modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep any condition according to the need of your program. For eg:

```
CLS
LET a = 5
WHILE a > 0
      PRINT a;
      a = a - 1
WEND
END
```

Here, in the program while wends executes itself until a = 0. This will not run an infinite loop.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is

```
exit();
```

to exit the program.

Comment: -1 This is a question about how to end the program using QBASIC, not C or C++. Actually, this isn't a correct answer for any of those languages since you pass an integer value to the function in both C and C++.